# java.lang. Error de versión de clase no soportada

Tags: java, compilacion

[image: Soy nuevo en este foro y no sé si se pueda hacer un zoom a la imagen pero igualmente la escribo]

Básicamente dice que ocurrió un error de JNI, que revise mi instalación e intente denuevo.

> Excepción en el hilo "main" java.lang. Error de versión de clase no soportada.

PrimeraClase (el nombre de mi archivo) fué compilado por una versión más reciente del Java Runtime( archivo de clase versión 58.0)
Esta versión de Java Runtime solo reconoce versiones de archivos de clase sobre la 52.0

Answer (score 1):

Es exactamente lo que dice, estás tratando de ejecutar una clase que fue compilada con una versión de java más nueva que tu runtime.
Prueba **java --version** para saber que runtime estás utilizando, y no puedo saber con qué compilaste tu clase, si lo hiciste con un IDE probablemente tenga configurado otra versión de compilador.

Comment: Ufff disculpa mi falta de entendimiento pero, valga al redundancia, no entendí muy bien. con el comando que me dijiste me dice que mi versión de java 1.8.0_251 y mi Runtime 1.8.0_251-b08.

Comment: Bueno, pero cómo compilaste esa clase?

Comment: con javac en la consola

Comment: igual dice que soporta de 52.0 hacia arriba y es 58.0

Comment: No, dice que soporta hasta la 52.0 (up to = hasta). 52.0 corresponde a Java 8, que es efectivamente la versión de tu runtime. 58.0 corresponde a Java 14, que es con lo que se compiló la clase. 
Has probado javac --version ?

Comment: Es curioso porque instalé el 8 , no me funcionó, instalé el 9 y me funcionó.